# is there a numeric up down or domain up down in universal windows app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I want to transform a windows form to univeral windows app. Because the logic is layered inside an assembly i don't have any problems but with UI i've been looking for a while in the toolbox and the internet but can't find the best option for the controls: 'numeric up down' and 'domain up down' of windows form.  So before to do anything, and in order to practise my english and comunicate with other people in world i ask this question:

is there a numeric up down or domain up down in universal windows app?

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 4):

[WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit) has one.

```
<controls:NumericUpDown Value="30"
                        Minimum="0"
                        Maximum="100"
                        SmallChange="1"
                        LargeChange="10" />
```